# Problem with style of ComboBox in material-design-in-xaml

Tags: material-design-in-xaml

I want to use the **MaterialDesignOutlinedComboBox** style for a Combobox but in my application it is not resolved (see image below of the styles proposed in visual studio)

[image: Available styles]

In the sample demo with code it is working just fine.
If I compare the theme/MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml and the one extracted from the package they are different.

I am using the latest package from nuget. What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the demo was not aligned to the 3.2.0 package. Recently the 4.0.0 went out and now everything is fitting.